# jboss operations network reports

Tags: jboss, reporting, monitoring

I have configured a JON server 3.1.0 and agents allowing to monitor JBoss AS.
I've set alerts to tell us when the process goes down and I now would like to export reports, especially with the availability/unavailability periods of the different processes.
It seems that the predefined reports concern more the utilization of the CPU/memory, but not the availability.
The purpose would be to export this report at the end of every month with the unavailability periods over the past month.

Is this possible? Does this exist by default? If yes, how can I access to this? If not, is there a way to get it?

Thanks for you support

Answer (score 1):

JON 3.1.0 should contain the REST-api as tech preview though (not sure). If this is in, you can use this to access the availability history e.g. via a http

```
GET localhost:7080/rest/resource/{id}/availability/history
```

with `{id}` being the id of the resource you need the report for.

Another option is the CLI, where you can write the output of the cli commands to a file.